# How to get ajax json loop response in javascript

Tags: php, json, ajax, loops

I am using ajax call for sending value to php file and get response back into first page,(work fine), but when i am  getting the result in loop form this response nothing will be return on first page.

My first page:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "action.php",
    method: "post",
    data: {
        'trader': selected_trader
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (response) {
        $('#date').html(response['date']);
        $('#symbol').html(response['symbol']);
        $('#status').html(response['status']);
        $('#alert').html(response['alert']);
        $('#company_name').html(response['company_name']);
    }
})
```

My 2nd page:

```
if (isset($_POST['trader'])) {
    $trader = $_POST['trader'];

    $sql = "Select * from current_trader where status='$trader' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data["date"] = date('Y:m:d', strtotime($row['date']));
        $data["symbol"] = $row['symbol'];
        $data["company_name"] = $row['company_name'];
        $data["alert"] = $row['alert'];
        $data["status"] = $row['status'];
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: what `console.log(response)` says into `success` block?

Comment: If the second page has multiple matches, your output will be invalid JSON (your ajax expects the result to be _one_ json object/array, while you're outputting multiple after each other) You should add all the data to an array: `$data[] = ['date' => date(..), 'symbol' => ... , etc];`and then json_encode the array _after_ the loop.

Comment: You're also **_wide open_** for SQL injection attacks. Use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with placeholders instead of injecting completely unescaped user data into the query like that. Never trust user data. It's also not only about security, but if the posted value would contain, say a `'`, the query would break.

Comment: I can not send data in array form it through an exception array to string convertion

Comment: Nothing  @mitkosoft